# Sending emails via PHP server

Tags: php, email

Straight to the point. I'm trying to set up a contact form on my website but struggling to make it work. Also have read through numerous of related topics here on SO. I followed tutorial thus I've got decent familiarity with this topic. I'm sure my php.ini file is configured just fine since sending emails worked until recently (although it always ended up in junk mail). Until I made changes to the code. Changes that I needed to make sooner or later. Strangely, sending emails worked when I ran it with hard-coded details with no variables. But when I implemented variables then it stopped working. Obviously I need PHP to process user's input through variables. How can get PHP to read user's input ? I think the most important part is using the attribute `name="something"` in input tags.

Sharing relevant code:

PHP:

```
<?php

$fullName = $errorMsg = $sucMsg = "";
$errMsg = $email = $subject = $emailErr = $message = "";

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;   
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fullName = test_input($_POST['fullName']);

    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Your email address is not valid !";        
    } else {
    $email = $_POST['email'];  
    }
    $subject = test_input($_POST['subject']);
    $message = test_input($_POST['message']);   

if($emailErr == "") {
        $emailTo = "mark.alexa.uk@gmail.com";
        $headers = "From ".$fullName." ".$email." via contact form";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: webmaster@ubuntuserver\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: alexa.mark@mail.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "BCC: alexa.mark@mail.com\r\n";

        if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            $sucMsg = "<p>The email was sent successfully !</p>";   
        } else {
            $errMsg = "<p>The email could not be sent !</p>";
        }
}

}   
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="form">

<div id="successMsg" class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><?php 
 echo $sucMsg; ?></div>
<div id="errMsg" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><?php echo 
 $errMsg; ?></div>
 <form method="POST" action="contact.php">
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="fullName">Full name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" 
id="fullName" placeholder="full name" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" class="form-
 control" required>
    <small id="emailHelp" name="email" class="form-text text-muted">I 
 won't share your email with anyone</small>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="subject" required> 
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Your message</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="message" required>

<input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

How should I modify the PHP code so it won't end up in junk mail ?

Comment: Have you tried to print out the variables to see their values?

Comment: Your headers should all end with \r\n.

Comment: `print_r($variable)`  correct ?

Comment: Oddly, `print_r($variable)` doesn't seem to show anything. I used `<?php
print_r($fullName);    ?>`   in HTML and expected it to pop up and nothing.

Comment: try print_r($_POST)

Comment: Yep ... output from the array showed all variables occupied as they should. I'm glad it's picking up on input well. Looks like I just need to find email service to deliver the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add name="submit" to your submit button. Forms pass on the name attribute to the post array. So your code test for:

```
if (isset(`$_POST['submit']`)) {
$fullName = test_input($_POST['fullName']);
```

..isn't valid because `$_POST['submit']` isn't set.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
```

Comment: @MarkyMark, you also forgot to add `name="email"` for your *email* input field.

Comment: Actually I typed it into the `small` tag by mistake lol. Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: Didin't know submit button need `name` too. Will fix it.

Comment: @Difster Mate, so it looks like the only real bug I had was absence of `name` attribute in the submit button tag. Thank you a million ! It works nicely. All input included in email that was sent. Can I update the question with follow-up question or do I have to create new topic ?

Comment: submit only needs a name if your'e going to test for it. The general rule is that any input that you want passed to your $_POST array has to have a name attribute.

Comment: @Difster  Will keep that in mind ! Any idea what should I do in order to receive the email as a standard email and not as a spam ?

Comment: This is so weird. It looks like it worked just once.

Comment: Did you make other changes after it worked once? Do a var_dump on your $_POST array and see what's there.

As for sending as spam, there's not a whole lot I can tell you there. You could try having it send through a known SMTP server or connecting with the MailChimp API, etc.

Comment: I see. Well as for email ending up in spam I guess PHP is too primitive to handle valid email processing that passes through Google's and Yahoo's spam filters. And no ... I didn't make any other changes other than adding the name attribute to the submit tag. That's why it's so odd.

Comment: There are a lot of factors that go in to getting directed to SPAM and it's different for each incoming email service. The factors go beyond programming aspects and have to do with reverse dns looksups and all kinds of other factors.

Comment: I guess I'll have to use some third-party email service. But what a shame. I really liked the idea of having my own server handle this.

Comment: I actually prefer a third party maintainer of email or using a more robust system like iRedMail.